# customizing devise_invitable email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer, devise-invitable

I have a rails app with default devise invitations. I'd like to change the email body and the subject line, but the default mailer looks like this:

/app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb

```
<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.hello", email: @resource.email) %></p>

<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.someone_invited_you", url: root_url) %></p>

<p><%= link_to t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.accept"), accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token) %></p>

<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.ignore").html_safe %></p>
```

I don't see how I could edit this.

I found this resource:
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Customizing-for-different-Invite-use-cases-(emails-etc.). 
As far as I understand it tells you how to change the subject and how to allow users to create a custom invite message.

But I don't want them to be able to create their own message. I just wanna send a system message that instead of saying "Somebody has invited you...", will dynamically insert the inviter's name like "John Smith has invited you..". I have first_name and last_name attributes in profile model that belongs_to user model, so I guess my mailer should contain something like @user.profile.first_name @user.profile.last_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
rails generate devise_invitable:views
```

And it'll generate local copies of the relevant views. Then you can edit that invite body in `/app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb`

Comment: mattkc7, I guess this is it. I mean what I pasted here is from invitation_instructions.html.erb. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I have another prbolem as well. If I invite sby who is already using the app then I get this error message: undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ff6bea58db0>

Comment: @SzilardMagyar what you pasted is a copy that was located in the gem. By running that command, it generated a local copy available for you to edit. For that other problem, you say you have an error when inviting someone who's already a user?

Comment: Also, to access the invitee, you can get the first name as: @resource.invited_by.first_name

Comment: I meant that this format was something that I'm not familiar with. Other mailers are plain html.erb unlike this one, so I just don't know how I can edit it. For example the unlock_instructions.html.erb looks like: <p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>. That's the normal, but this one is <p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.hello", email: @resource.email) %></p> and I don't see how to deal with it.

Comment: For the second one, yeah, if I try to invite sby who is already using the app then I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: for t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.hello", email: @resource.email), that's accessing the devise.yml file for Il8n (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), which has a list of template sentences/phrases/etc. You can make local changes to that, but i removed it altogether and threw in my own sentence. I think it's the devise.yml file. As for inviting a user already part of the app, i have yet to get to that part yet (i started on this only a few hours ago!)

Comment: Thanks mattkc. I see, I will check it out. I was just surprised because all the others were the same html.erb and this one just didn't fit into the picture.

Comment: have u found something regarding the 2nd problem? Haven't you run into that before?

Comment: I could not reproduce the error when inviting someone who 1) was already a user or 2) had a pending invite. I did read in the devise_invitable github page about 'resend_invitation' which says "resend_invitation: resend invitation if user with invited status is invited again. Enabled by default." Is yours turned off? Also, looking at the error your posted about the input/formBuilder, it looks like the form you are posting might be malformed or something is off (ie. using simple_form and a feature that's not in the regular rails form_for tag?)